# Printing elements of Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, twitter

I have an Array of data returned from a Twitter API call in an Array. I'm iterating the "Top 10 Trending" however cannot print the individual elements, e.g. name. Below is the code I am using to get as far as I can:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
echo "</pre>";
```

**This results in the below:**

```
Array
(
    [trends] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => #PagiYlanissa
                    [query] => %23PagiYlanissa
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23PagiYlanissa
                    [promoted_content] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Torikul SMKN2 SRAGEN
                    [query] => %22Torikul+SMKN2+SRAGEN%22
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Torikul+SMKN2+SRAGEN%22
                    [promoted_content] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Wali Supit Tamfan Dan Berani
                    [query] => %22Wali+Supit+Tamfan+Dan+Berani%22
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Wali+Supit+Tamfan+Dan+Berani%22
                    [promoted_content] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => #SelamatMalamNadyaFatira
                    [query] => %23SelamatMalamNadyaFatira
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23SelamatMalamNadyaFatira
                    [promoted_content] => 
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [name] => #fireproof
                    [query] => %23fireproof
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23fireproof
                    [promoted_content] => 
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Bersyukur
                    [query] => Bersyukur
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=Bersyukur
                    [promoted_content] => 
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Selamat Hari Olahraga Nasional
                    [query] => %22Selamat+Hari+Olahraga+Nasional%22
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Selamat+Hari+Olahraga+Nasional%22
                    [promoted_content] => 
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [name] => #RIPRise
                    [query] => %23RIPRise
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23RIPRise
                    [promoted_content] => 
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Tanggal 9
                    [query] => %22Tanggal+9%22
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Tanggal+9%22
                    [promoted_content] => 
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [name] => #LP3IPastiKerja
                    [query] => %23LP3IPastiKerja
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23LP3IPastiKerja
                    [promoted_content] => 
                )

        )

    [as_of] => 2014-09-08T23:30:17Z
    [created_at] => 2014-09-08T23:25:24Z
    [locations] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Indonesia
                    [woeid] => 23424846
                )

        )

)
```

However I cannot access the individual elements through the Array at the top. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you access them through `$string[0]['trends']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
foreach ($string[0]['trends'] as $trending)
{
  extract($trending);
  echo $name.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$trends = $string[0]['trends'];

foreach ($trends as $trend) {
    // Do stuff with $trend['name'], $trend['query'], etc.
}
```